# ReReplace any word that begins with @

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

I'm trying to rereplace any words that begin with @ in my string...

I've tried a number of variations, but none of them seem to be working...

```
rereplace(getMessages.term, "[\s]?\B@\w+", "", "ALL")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add an example to test with?

Comment: rereplace("@CaylaCharnise were twins remember! I'm having a little influenza here:(",  "[\s]?\B@\w+", "", "ALL")

Comment: The goal is to strip out @CaylaChamise from the string

Comment: @TheJason: It would be better for you to add that information to the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CF's built-in regex doesn't support look-behinds, which is what you need to achieve this (since you want to look "behind" (before) the @ and verify what is/isn't there, without including it in your match).

However you can easily dip into Java, to make use of Java's regex support (which does support look-behinds), as simply as this:

```
<cfset Text = Text.replaceAll('(?<!\w)@\w+','') />
```

The `(?<!\w)` part is a negative look-behind saying "make sure there is no \w before this position".

You might also want to consider using `(?<!\S)` which will prevent any non-whitespace character, or if you need to match specific characters then use `(?<![a-z_\-.,])` or whatever.